# SQLite object can't be set in UWP - Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin.forms, uwp, xamarin.uwp

Please consider the following problem:

I am attempting to use an SQLite database in a Xamarin Forms app across iOS, Android and Windows 10 devices.

I have my database model at portable level and use an interface to implement platform specific SQLite connections as per documentation, my iOS and Android implementations work just fine, but I can't seem to get my UWP version working. It appears that whenever I try to do anything with my `SQLiteConnection database` object, I get the exception `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

Please see my PCL and device specific code below:

**Database.cs (Shared)**

```
public class Database
{
    static object locker = new object();
    public static SQLiteConnection database;

    public Database()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Attempting to build connection");
        try
        {
            if(database == null)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("DATABASE IS NULL");
            }

            database = DependencyService.Get<ISQLite>().GetConnection(); // <- Crashes here with: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
            Debug.WriteLine("Get Type: " + database.GetType().ToString());
            Debug.WriteLine("DB Path: " + database.DatabasePath);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

        database.CreateTable<User>();
    }
}
```

**ISQLite_Windows.cs (Device specific)**

```
class ISQLite_Windows : ISQLite
{
    public ISQLite_Windows()
    {
    }

    public SQLiteConnection GetConnection()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("This debug never seems to fire");
        var sqliteFilename = "EventManagementSystem.db3";
        string path = Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, sqliteFilename);
        var conn = new SQLiteConnection(path);
        Debug.WriteLine("Connection made, returning");
        return conn;
    }
}
```

**Useful Info**

I am using the beta NuGet package for `sqlite-net-pcl` Version 1.5.166-beta as that appears to be the suggested choice for UWP.

I am using version 5.2.2 for the NuGet package `Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform`

The app builds and intellisense has picked up no errors, but during App.cs initialization it breaks.

I can't seem to find the database file being created on my machine, although I suspect this is due to it breaking before it gets that far. The problem seems more to do with accessing the database object at shared level, rather than the device specific implementation, although I may very well be wrong about this.

Comment: I believe it's database = DependencyService.Get<ISQLite>().GetConnection();

Comment: Well, that throws an exception which is caught, but any other reference to database seems to do the same, the GetConnection is just the first time I try and do anything with database

Comment: You are absolutely right, it was not being registered correctly. Thank you very much! If you would like to put this as an answer, I will gladly accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction) state:

> Registration – Each implementing class must be registered with
>   DependencyService via a metadata attribute. Registration enables
>   DependencyService to find the implementing class and supply it in
>   place of the interface at run time.

The most likely cause of your issue is that `ISQLite` does not have an implementing class that has been registered.